# (UE4) Is there a method of getting all actors in camera view?

Tags: trace, unreal-engine4

Like the title says, i want to be able to get all actors that are within the camera view in Unreal Engine 4.

I have thought of two ways i could do this: 1) using a shape trace in the form of a "boxtracebyobject" which works but seems to be glitchy at times and has trouble recognizing multiple overlapping actors. 2) using a "BoxOverlappingActors", though i havent quite figured out how to use it yet.

If anyone knows of a proper method to getting actors in cameria view, my ears are open!

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

[A much better answer has been posted on Unreal Answers by Rama](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/21801/check-if-an-object-is-visible-by-a-camera.html#post-21947-score):

Use the `AActor::GetLastRenderTime()` to find out for each actor when last drawn or `UPrimitiveComponent::LastRenderTime` for the primitive itself. His answer explains how you can use this.

**Original answer:**

As you suggested, it seems weird that you would have to do something to do with collision volumes when Unreal must be checking to do culling so I found the following method to query that information:

First we have to create a `FSceneView` from the camera. [This code is taken from the UE Answers question](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/158008/get-fsceneview-for-inactive-camera.html).

```
APlayerCameraManager* Manager = World->GetFirstPlayerController()->PlayerCameraManager;
ULocalPlayer* LocalPlayer = World->GetFirstLocalPlayerFromController();

FSceneViewFamilyContext ViewFamily(FSceneViewFamily::ConstructionValues(
    LocalPlayer->ViewportClient->Viewport,
    World->Scene,
    LocalPlayer->ViewportClient->EngineShowFlags)
    .SetRealtimeUpdate(true));

FVector ViewLocation;
FRotator ViewRotation;
FSceneView* SceneView = LocalPlayer->CalcSceneView(&ViewFamily, /*out*/ ViewLocation, /*out*/ ViewRotation, LocalPlayer->ViewportClient->Viewport);
```

Once we've created the view we can iterate through all primitive components (includes meshes) and then we can  use the bounds from the `SceneProxy` of the Static Mesh and the bounds of the view to do our own culling.

```
for (TObjectIterator<UPrimitiveComponent> ScenePrimitsItr; ScenePrimitsItr; ++ScenePrimitsItr)
{
    // Using the Object iterator so we have to skip objects not in the 
    // relevant world
    if (ScenePrimitsItr->GetWorld() == World)
    {
        FPrimitiveSceneProxy* Proxy = ScenePrimitsItr->SceneProxy;
        if (Proxy)
        {
            bool bIsShown = 
                SceneView->ViewFrustum.IntersectSphere(Proxy->GetBounds().Origin, Proxy->GetBounds().SphereRadius)||
                SceneView->ViewFrustum.IntersectBox(Proxy->GetBounds().Origin, Proxy->GetBounds().BoxExtent);
        }
    }
}
```

The frustrum check came from SceneVisibility.cpp in the method `FrustumCull` This method isn't ideal as a) involves duplicating that check and b) performing the test twice. However, I couldn't find a way to actually query the result. It appears to be stored in a bit array in the `FViewInfo`. Unfortunately this info is not exposed outside of the renderer module.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this to create an array of actors: [image]

But I don't know if it's good performance wise if there are too many actors of the class you want.

Comment: This could possibly be the answer, however, is there a way to limit the get all actors of class to just those of that class AND the view of the camera?